# How do you exclude @skips from Serenity reports while running JBehave tests?

Tags: java, skip, jbehave, thucydides

So we have tests that look like this:

```
Scenario: XXX- 9056: Change password to special characters
Meta:
@Regression
@ticket #5732
@skip
Given a customer with the following properties:...
```

we put the `@skip` there whenever we are still working on it or we know it will not work properly.

We want to get Serenity reports, but we don't want it to include skipped stories. How can we exclude them from being reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found our issue was that in the Scenario line some of our test cases looked like

> Scenario: XXX-#9056: Change password to special characters

Instead of

> Scenario: XXX- 9056: Change password to special characters

So having the pound symbol(#) on the line with Scenario was messing it up. It doesn't matter if it is under the meta tag. Now none of the skipped test are showing in the report.